# Help with sed regex: extract text from specific tag

Tags: html, xml, regex, sed, grep

First time sed'er, so be gentle.

I have the following text file, 'test_file':

```
 <Tag1>not </Tag1><Tag2>working</Tag2>
```

I want to extract the text in between `<Tag2>` using sed regex, there may be other occurrences of `<Tag2>` and I would like to extract those also.

So far I have this sed based regex:

```
cat test_file | grep -i "Tag2"| sed 's/<[^>]*[>]//g'
```

which gives the output:

```
 not working
```

Anyone any idea how to get this working?

Comment: From what you have written, I am guessing you only need the text between the Tag2 tags. Is that correct? If that is the case, do you know what cat test_file | grep -i "Tag2" outputs?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Sorry to say this, but posting *the link* in reaction to a regex+(x)html related question without providing any more information, is perhaps as tiring as the question itself. Come to think of it, it's even more so. It's the equivalent of posting the notorious quote "programmer *bla bla bla* problem *couch* regex *gulp* has two problems!". If you feel the uncontrollable urge to post the link, at least give the original poster a slight indication of what s/he is about to do is not the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

As another poster said, sed may not be the best tool for this job. You may want to use something built for XML parsing, or even a simple scripting language, such as perl.

The problem with your try, is that you aren't analyzing the string properly.

`cat test_file` is good - it prints out the contents of the file to stdout.

`grep -i "Tag2"` is ok - it prints out only lines with "Tag2" in them. This may not be exactly what you want. Bear in mind that it will print the *whole* line, not just the <Tag2> part, so you will still have to search out that part later.

`sed 's/&lt;[^&gt;]*[&gt;]//g'` isn't what you want - it simply removes the tags, including <Tag1> *and* <Tag2>.

You can try something like:

```
cat tmp.tmp | grep -i tag2 | sed 's/.*<Tag2>\(.*\)<\/Tag2>.*/\1/'
```

This will produce

```
working
```

but it will only work for one tag pair.

Comment: +1 for **NOT** posting *the link* and patiently answering the question as well as warning that it is not a general solution to the problem.

Answer (score 4):

For your nice, friendly example, you could use

```
sed -e 's/^.*<Tag2>//' -e 's!</Tag2>.*!!' test-file
```

but the XML out there is cruel and uncaring. You're asking for serious trouble using regular expressions to scrape XML.

Comment: +1 for **NOT** posting *the link* and patiently answering the question as well as warning that it is not a general solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use gawk, eg

```
$ cat file
 <Tag1>not </Tag1><Tag2>working here</Tag2>
 <Tag1>not </Tag1><Tag2>
working

</Tag2>

$ awk -vRS="</Tag2>" '/<Tag2>/{gsub(/.*<Tag2>/,"");print}' file
working here

working
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"Tag2" '{print $2}' test_1 | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z]//g'
```